# vHow to upload my GIT Master Branch to my server Over SSH?

Tags: ssh, git

I want to upload all my project files to the server over SSH, I want to avoid guessing what files I need to upload.

I know Git does this when remote pushing to GitHub but I need to upload it directly to my server instead of GitHub.

Comment: Do you need to make a git repo, or do you just want to copy the files to somewhere on your server?

Answer (score 0):

Set up a git repository at your server, then you can push stuff over there with no problems. Check the documentation at http://www.git-scm.com (there are several tutorials, and even a complete book). Check the documentation of git on how to configure remote branches.